# Faulty WLAN Card on a Dell E4310

Tags: wireless-networking

One day, I could not connect to the internet, and I realized that the radio light was not on, and I do not remember turning off the radio or I would know where to turn it on again.

After searching on Google to see if it was due to driver issue, I found something like this:

[image]

I don't know what this broadcom USH / Unknown driver is, looking at the properties of the unknown:

[image]

This is the broadcom USH:

[image]

How would I know if my WLAN card is actually faulty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the WLAN card is seated properly in the socket.  Download and install the drivers.  if it is still not working, then call Dell for support.